# Should I Unite 3 Answers In 1?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, multiple-answers

Currently thinking about this question here:
[What is similar function with "Range.Find" vba's method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580188/what-is-similar-function-with-range-find-vbas-method-in-python/)

where I have put 3 answers, answering the question. Should I unite them in one to to make it better or it makes sense to leave them as they are?

---

And now I feel guilty for even asking, as the question is going to be closed.

Comment: _"Should I unite them in one to avoid downvotes "_ I doubt that will have the desired effect.

Comment: If you can write three different answers to a question it is probably too broad.

Comment: That question is too broad, lacking an MCVE or any sign of attempting to solve the issue from the OP's end, and is basically a tool / library request. Your best course of action would've been to _close_ it, instead of answering it.

Comment: That pretty much is one answer just spread across three. I vote for merging

Comment: @Cerbrus - if every question without MCVE was closed, then about 95% of the question in SO would be out.

Comment: @Vityata: Yes, but SO isn't a free code-writing service. We expect ___some___ measure of effort.

Comment: I think what you did is correct. 3 different solutions, using different libraries, work well as different answers. If you wish to compare them in-line, then consider merging. Just be prepared for downvotes with your approach, many cynics on SO may see your behaviour as rep-hunting (or they may not like the question, so DV x 3). If you couldn't care less about this subset of users, then your solutions look fine.

Comment: @jpp: I'm pretty sure downvoting all 3 answers will result in a serial-voting reversal.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Not if they're clever, a downvote a day keeps the reversal script away :)

Comment: @jpp - I am afraid to ask how do you know it...

Comment: @Cerbrus It should be easy enough to detect that you're just voting on a bunch of answers on one question, which seems like a reasonable (if arguable) signal that you're voting on content and not targeting a specific user. Although I have no idea whether they do this and the multiple-answers-by-one-person could also be a rare enough thing to not specifically be protected against serial voting.

Comment: @Dukeling While they could indeed check for that, I'm pretty sure that they don't.

Comment: @Dukeling They don't. I already ran into this once when i downvoted 3 answers on a question by a single user.

Comment: MSE duplicate - [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

Comment: @Dukeling - I completely ignore that community after receiving about `-50` on a question.

Comment: @Vityata What would be wrong with closing 95% of the questions **when they deserve to be closed**?

Comment: @AndréKool - this sounds like a separate topic. In general it is not done, thus I guess there is a reason for it.

Comment: @jpp - thanks for [the nice words](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368756/should-i-unite-3-answers-in-one?noredirect=1#comment595671_368756), I am trying. :)

Comment: If they <s>has enough popularity</s> are actually useful someone will definitely upvote them. Some downvotes should not matter.

Comment: @user202729 - thank you, I probably got an idea why the 7 downvotes (and counting) are on this question. I have edited.

Comment: @Vityata, The truth is there are cynics on Meta (who  are <unsubstantiated_claim>the type who *would* downvote your answers</unsubstantiated_claim> if they came across them). Multiple answers are often a great idea. I often see a bad solution followed  by a good one in one answer and wish the former was just removed. Generally, *removing* material (good or bad) tends to be contentious / might not satisfy some egos. But voting is a useful way to communicate approval / disapproval of *different methods*.

Comment: @jpp - so true. And I was just expecting a nice discussion about 3 answers vs 1 answer.

Comment: [1/2] Tangential note on the status of the main site question: My gut feeling is that the "recommendation" close votes were appropriate. While there are special cases of questions of this sort that I would advise treating with leniency, processing Excel files feels too much of a domain-specific task for this one to qualify. On the other hand, your answers already exist and are useful -- it would be a shame to lose them at this point. That being so, I suggest rewriting the question to remove the recommendation aspect and make it primarily about using XlsxWriter to do what the OP there wants to.

Comment: [2/2] One question that might be raised is whether such a rewrite would invalidate the xlwings answer. At this point, I'm tempted to answer "who cares", and suggest merely adding a suitable disclaimer on the top of it. If you feel that would be too cavalier, there is always the alternative of reposting that specific answer through a self-answered question, and then linking to it in the comments of the rewritten question.

Comment: @Vityata I went ahead and performed the rewrite. Let's bring it back!

Comment: @Vityata It's an honor that you willing to share your answer to me. It was sad that I want to vote one of your best answer but the post already deleted. For those community that agreed my post should be deleted, I'm accepted the reason you has raised. The only forum that I can think and only I can believe is stackoverflow and I thought this forums can shared the opinion to others which is maybe useful to others vba programmer like me. I want to ask, is there any suitable forum that can be discussed for sharing opinion such as my post?

Comment: I know that my profile is not popular enough to get vote for undeleted. I also research and know about the link that provided by @ashleedawg but still it was fixing the range. FYI, my question previously asking about what suitable package or any functions that already available in python. Please don't get me wrong. I just want to explain to you guys what am I asking. Last but not least, please also guide me the suitable forum that I can joined for me to ask the opinion regarding Python package. Thanks all and have a nice day :)

Comment: [1/2] @user2851376 The gist of it is that here (1) opinions take a backseat; and (2) "How to do" questions work better than "where to find" ones. As I see it, your question would be fine if you had left out "share or suggest the suitable packages" part, and made it clear where the `range()` method you tried to use came from, thus giving sufficient context for a concrete answer. That is what I'm trying to achieve with my edit. (I'm using the present tense because there is a chance the question will be restored -- it has two undelete votes already.)

Comment: [2/2] @user2851376 It is very much worth noting that this trimming down of your question wouldn't stop it from being useful to you. Vityata's XlsxWriter answers would remain relevant, and ashleedawg would still have been able to leave their commenting pointing out the xlwings alternative.

Comment: @duplode I see..Thanks a lot for your editing, I will try to edit my question again but it will take sometimes as currently, I had a lot of commitment. Thanks all! :)

Comment: @duplode - thank you for editing the question and looking at it in such a great detail! :)

Comment: @user2851376 - you are welcome :) In general, I guess that in LinkedIn are some groups discussing Excel & Python. Or Quora.com.

Comment: The question is still a "feature request / write my code / gimme a library" question. That didn't warrant undeleting.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Feature request[s]" aren't, in general, off-topic, and "gimme a library" is hardly applicable if the question doesn't actually ask for a library. I believe that significantly weakens the case for closure.

Comment: @duplode: You conveniently forgot to answer the _"write my code"_ description I mentioned. This is a zero-context code request that has 3 possible answers, the question is way too broad.

Comment: TL;DR: Let it die already.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Write my code" is not a close reason on its own either. It may cause a question to be too broad, but it depends on the how much code the asker is looking for, and on how well specified the task is. I wouldn't describe this question as "zero-context": the reference to the VBA method gives a clear reference point, even if it is abstracted away from a concrete problem. Lastly, having more than one answer doesn't make, by itself, the question too broad.

Comment: The question is too broad, it's closed as such, but for some silly reason, it's got re-open votes. It's deleted because it's just a request for code. It's not going to help ___any___ future visitors. The request is ___useless___ without the link it's linking to, so as soon as that link breaks, the question is even more pointless. We all know how much Microsoft likes to break help center links. I can't believe you're arguing that the question isn't "too broad". There are 3 _completely_ different approaches there, and I can easily see 3 more ways to do that.

Comment: @Cerbrus "The question is too broad, it's closed as such" -- The question was closed as a recommendation question, and not as too broad. On "not going to help any future visitors", given that the question is looking for a feature implemented elsewhere in terms abstracted from a concrete problem, I don't think "too localised" would apply, if you want to look at it from that angle. The link in the question points to MSDN documentation, and the question text mentions what it is pointing to, so using that to justify closure is a stretch.

Comment: @duplode: All those reasons _on their own_ might not be enough, but all of those apply to the question. There is just _too much wrong_ with it.

Comment: Furthermore, at the time it was closed, it _was_ a library request. The close reason might've shifted, but there's no point in re-opening it just to close it again. That's a ___waste of time.___

Comment: @Cerbrus My argument boils down to regarding most of those reasons as not actually applicable here. In any case, I'll let the matter rest for the moment.

Comment: @duplode Fyi, I already editing the question hope that it can be re-open again so that both you and Vityata effort is not wasted. Shall wait for their answer. Cheers

Comment: @Cerbrus Fyi, I already editing the question and please check whether its meet the criteria or not as I dont want to waste Vityata answer which is provide 3 different solutions, which is totally great idea. I already test with others package, I including my code as well and also got reference from VBA to make others understanding for what I want to found so far. Hope enough to satisfied all of the community. Cheers

Comment: @Vityata and user2851376: The one additional suggestion I'd make is about being careful so that the edits not end up invalidating Vityata's answers. For instance, I would not have added the [win32com] tag, as that might be taken as restricting the scope of answers to solutions that use that specific library.

Comment: @duplode Already removed [win32com] tag :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It can be reasonable to post multiple answers to a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348403/2751851). I would say the criteria to decide whether doing so is a good idea boil down to:

- The solutions should be essentially independent from each other; and
- The solutions should be sufficiently different from each other to justify the overhead of posting them as multiple answers. That includes:

  - The concepts or approaches employed in the solutions being markedly distinct; and
  - The solutions being sufficiently disjoint that combining them in a single answer would muddle up moderation ("can I upvote just half of this answer") or make the text unwieldy ("those section headers feel like chapters in a book").

As far as your three answers are concerned, my gut feeling is that the two XlsxWriter ones could (and probably should) be merged, as the difference between the solutions in them seems to be a relatively minor matter of code organisation. A clear advantage of doing so would be that it wouldn't be necessary to duplicate the boilerplate-ish code that generates sample data for demonstrating the solutions. As for the xlwings solution, it uses an entirely different approach, and so it does make sense to have it as a separate answer.

(For the sake of argument, I'm assuming the xlwings answer fits the question. Whether that actually is, or should be, the case is a separate matter I'm not addressing in this answer.)